# History substitution is messing with command line arguments

Tags: shell, command-line, sh, expect, command-line-tool

I'm running an *expect* script that takes username, password from command line.
However, password contains **!!** (eg: **pass!!word**)

But shell is expanding this to previous command (read [this link](https://www.ostechnix.com/5-ways-repeat-last-command-linux/))

How to escape this?

Comment: Single quote the password variable, to not let the shell interpret it as a special character

Comment: Thanks. It worked. 
We had tried with double quotes, but we didn't try with single quotes.